# 'Vagrant up doesn't work as expected, Code E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vagrant

```
PS C:\desktop\laravel-les1> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'laravel-les1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> laravel-les1: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\Aqsa Intizar\\.vagrant.d\\boxes\\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead\\8.1.0\\virtualbox\\box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "ubuntu-18.04-amd64_1569415942892_47656", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "11", "--disk", "C:/Users/Aqsa Intizar/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu-18.04-amd64_1569415942892_47656/ubuntu-18.04-amd64-disk001.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting \\?\C:\Users\Aqsa Intizar\.vagrant.d\boxes\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead\8.1.0\virtualbox\box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: E_INVALIDARG
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057) - One or more arguments are invalid (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 957 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-VM vagrantfile fails on second machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1410520/multi-vm-vagrantfile-fails-on-second-machine)

Answer (score 2):

Please check the existence of the file specified at this path :

`C:\Users\Aqsa Intizar\.vagrant.d\boxes\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead\8.1.0\virtualbox\box.ovf`

If the file does exist, here's what you can try :
open VirtualBox GUI and ensure there are no existing VM based on your box, if there are, delete them, and try to `vagrant up` after that.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if the path configured for Default Machine Folder in the VBox File->Preferences->General exists.

[VBox Preferences dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9M2R.png)

I had the problem after migrating to another user account which did not have the VM path that was configured in the global installation.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

1- check you have enough space in your drive c:

2- make sure your C:\Users\Aqsa Intizar.vagrant.d\boxes\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead\8.1.0\virtualbox\box.ovf is up to date

Comment: For me it was the disk space